# How to export downloaded audio file(from within app folder) to user accessible music folder in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, file-sharing

I am using Xamarin to develop an IOS app. Here the user has an option to download audio files to the document folder within the app, and play it later on.

But i would like to provide an option for the user to access it in music folder or somewhere else, so that user does not have to come back to app to listen it.
Like we save images to camera roll, can we save mp3 or any other audio file to default music folder in IOS. Any solution or ideas using xamarin or xcode are welcome.

Note: I already know about File Sharing with itunes, i am looking for something else explained above.

Answer (score 0):

As I know this isn't possible due to the limitations within iOS

Comment: is it not possible with xamarin ios sdk OR the native xcode ios sdk. please elaborate